# Trying to append elements to multi-dimensional array. Exception thrown when trying to run the application

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

```
int main()
{
    int r;
    scanf("%d", &r);
    int **arr = (int *)malloc(r * r * sizeof(int));
    *(*(arr + r) + r);

    for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= r; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter element %d.%d: \n", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i-1][j-1]);
        }

    }
    getch();
}
```

so this recently happened, basically what I want is to append matrix elements to 2d array, but it says

'Exception thrown at 0x0F1B97AE (ucrtbased.dll) in Matrix.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD'

don`t know what to do :( help please

Comment: What's up with this line? `*(*(arr + r) + r);` Anyway, you need to use pointer arithmetic to access the array elements as it has been allocated at runtime.

Comment: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

You're using a malloc'ed block of memory as a C multi-dimensional array. Instead, you need to use a single set of square brackets.

Instead of `arr[i-1][j-1]`, you need something like `arr[i * r + j]`.

I'm surprised that most compilers would accept this by default because you use an `int *` to initialize and `int **`.

Comment: it works ! but throws another exception when I try to print out elements  `printf("%d", arr[i][j])` do I have to access them with something like `arr[i * r + j]` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't allocate or create a "two-dimensional" array. Your memory allocation allocates *one* array of `r * r` elements.

This single array can't be used as an array of arrays.

The usual solution to create a dynamic array of arrays is to create a *jagged* array:

```
int **arr = malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
for (unsigned i = 0; i < r; ++i)
{
    arr[i] = malloc(r * sizeof(int));
}
```

---

You *can* use a large single array in a "two-dimensional" way, but you need to use some other arithmetic to access the elements of it:

```
arr[i * r + j]
```

<sub>[Note that the above requires zero-based indexes `i` and `j`]</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
int **arr = (int *)malloc(r * r * sizeof(int));
```

You can't create a 2D array with a single allocation like that, at least not one you can access with a `int **`.  What you have instead is space for `r * r`, objects of type `int` which can be accessed via a `int *` and some additional arithmetic.

When you later do this:

```
*(*(arr + r) + r);
```

The first dereference is fine, since `arr` points to an allocated buffer.  The second one is not, however, because you read an uninitialized value from that allocated buffer and attempt to use to as a valid address.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this cause results in a crash.

You need to allocate space for an array of `int *`, they for each of those allocate an array of `int`:

```
int **arr = malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(r * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Of course you can create it with a single allocation, that's the proper and most correct way. But you will have to drop the `int**` thing, since it can't point at a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

Just forget all about this `int**` nonsense and allocate a 2D array instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int r;
    scanf("%d", &r);
    int (*arr)[r] = malloc( sizeof(int[r][r]) );

    for (int i = 0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<r; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = 1; // some sort of input here
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

Output example with input 5:

```
5
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

For this to work, you need a standard-compliant C compiler from this millennium.

More information: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: doesn`t work, it says that 'r' has to be a constant value

Comment: @СтепанБандера It works just fine. See the sentence "For this to work, you need a standard-compliant C compiler from this millennium." Apparently you are using a dinosaur compiler.

Comment: sorry for not seeing, I`m using Visual Studio 2017, is it bad ?

Comment: @СтепанБандера Yeah it is bad. In C mode, it is a dinosaur compiler from the early 1990s. Microsoft has pretty much dropped their support for C and VS is best off if regarded as a C++ only compiler.

Comment: what should I use ?

Comment: @СтепанБандера gcc, clang, icc, whatever compiler that's updated. Codeblocks with the default gcc/Mingw installation under Windows is both free and beginner-friendly.

Comment: thanks for advice, I will definitely try it, but my professor at uni only wants us to use VS 2017... can I change compiler in VS ?

Comment: @СтепанБандера You can set it to "C mode" somehow, but then it barely follows the 30 years old C90 standard.